# Excessing Maps in python matplotlib graps

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a Tkinter based application in python which tracks the movement of users and plot them on a graph.
now ploting the points on a graph is no biggie, but what i couldnt manage was to give the background image as a map

currently my progress for this particular feature is nothing but as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
a=[[],[]]
a[0]=[12.28384,12,23434]#100's of values extracted from some csv file
a[1]=[80.12332,80.13312]#consider a[0],a[1] as latitude,longitude respectively
plt.plot(a[0],a[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This answer explains how to set an image background in tkinter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181434/2570277

Comment: i know how to add a single image, but my problem is vaster, location data is not limited to a single image. so i wanted to use maps directly.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445072/2570277) explains how to embed a map in a Tkinter window and may help.

You could also look at this example that uses the [GooMPy](https://github.com/simondlevy/GooMPy/blob/master/example.py) library to embed an interactive google map in a Tkinter window.